# git diff with matlab package directory

Tags: git, matlab, git-diff, vimdiff

I'm having issue running `git dff` with `+Dir01/file.m`.

I think the problem is with the + in the directory name. How can I get `git diff` to work with this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What difficulties? What error? I'm having an issue understanding this question.

Comment: I get an error 

`errr while processing command line
Not an editor command +Dir01/file.m `

Comment: @Adriaan I get the same error with vim. So I guess since i'm using vimdiff for my git difftool, the same error persists. My guess is that vim doesn't like + in the directory name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim does not like opening files that have a leading `+` character. You can try prefacing your path with `./`.

```
git diff ./+Dir01/file.m
```

Another way that you can open these types of files with vim is to use `--` to indicate that no options should be passed, and then vim won't treat the `+` as a command.

```
vim -- +Dir01/file.m
```

Knowing this, you could use the `-x` argument for `git difftool`.

```
git difftool -x "vimdiff --"
```

You could update your `.git/config` with the following:

```
git config --global difftool.vimdiff.cmd "vimdiff -- \"\$LOCAL\" \"\$REMOTE\""
```

Comment: thank you. That works for `diff` but not for `git difftool`. Any suggestion for `difftool`?

Comment: @kirikoumath Updated with a solution for `git difftool`

Comment: my config for the diff is
`[diff]
    tool = vimdiff
[difftool]
    prompt = false
`
so how should I change the `tool = vimdiff` line?

Comment: because when I try your `difftool.vimdiff.cmd` I get an error

`fatal: bad config file line 62 in .gitconfig`

Comment: Can you paste what your config looks like after running that.

Comment: `[branch "master"]
    remote = bucket
    merge = refs/heads/master
[difftool "vimdiff"]
    cmd = vimdiff -- \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
`

Comment: now that works. But this is in my local config file.

Comment: @kirikoumath oh ok. So you'll just want to add `--global` to the `git config` line

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thank you so much.